# combine image and counter in enumerate list

Tags: enumerate

I am using the enumitem package to customise my list. That works fine, however I would like to combine images and the counter to each item in an easy way. What I tried:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\thechapter.\arabic*, font=\normalfont, wide= 4pt, leftmargin=*]

\item[{\includegraphics{Bluestar.eps} \value{enumi}}] \refstepcounter{enumi} first is blue 
\item[{\includegraphics{Redstar.eps} \value{enumi}}] \refstepcounter{enumi} second is red
\item[{\includegraphics{Greenstar.eps} \value{enumi}}] \refstepcounter{enumi} third is green
\end{enumerate}
```

but does not compile. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Ilias

Answer (score 1):

Here an option you can insert your images like this

```
\begin{enumerate}
\Item(first-image) first is blue 
\Item(second-image) second is red
\Item(third-image) third is green
\end{enumerate}
```

The width of inserted images is `1cm`, you can modify it within `\labelenumi` command which hold item label.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]\ima~\arabic{enumi}}
\def\Item(#1){\def\ima{#1}\item}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\Item(example-image) first is blue 
\Item(example-image-a) second is red
\Item(example-image-b) third is green
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a log for the reply and the solution. Would work for me, unfortunately the images I want to put in my lists are not ordered by number so cannot be referenced as \ima~\arabic{enumi}. My present solution is to define a fully custom list, but I was after an easy implementation using the enumerate and enumitem packages.

Comment: Name of image is stored in `\ima` command and used inside `\labelenumi` macro as argument of `\includgraphics`, `~` is added just to create space between image and numbering you can use also just `\ `.